# Python - write files while following an order

Tags: python, file

I have the data saved in a dictionary, such as:

```
{'CTY': '897', 'LC': '7W', 'DIV': '7W', 'MAJ': '018', 'MINOR': '0100', 'SMIN': '0010', 'INS_TIME_STAMP': datetime.datetime(2016, 3, 8, 17, 37, 40, 897812)}
```

I would like to have the Keys copied into a txt, and then the values copied as well.  My expected result is:

```
CTY LC DIV MAJ MINOR SMIN INS_TIME_STAMP
897 7W 7W  018 0100  0010 2016-03-08 17:37:40.897812
```

You can notice that the value starts at the same column as the key.

This is what I tried so far:

```
with open('Archivo.txt', 'a') as a:
        to_write = []

        filtered_dict = {key: value for key, value in query_result.items() if not isinstance(key, int)}
        column_names = [key for key in filtered_dict.keys()]
        columns = " ".join(column_names)
        a.write(columns + '\n')

        result_values = [str(value) for value in filtered_dict.values()]
        values = " ".join(result_values)
        a.write(values + '\n')
```

Which results in:

```
CTY LC DIV MAJ MINOR SMIN INS_TIME_STAMP
897 7W 7W 018 0100 0010 2016-03-08 17:37:40.897812
```

Comment: Have you tried using `\t`?

Comment: please help us to understand what the problem is. The result and expected result are the same. thanks.

Comment: your expected and actual output seems to be the same. The only difference I see is the spacing. Are you asking how to space the second row?

Comment: Yes, I am asking about the spacing in the second row.

Comment: I am not familiar with \t

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If what you're after is human readability in a txt file, you can use the '\t' string literal for ASCII horizontal tab. Be aware that some values might be too long and one tab might not be enough to pad the column out.

`columns = "\t".join(column_names)`
`values = "\t".join(result_values)`

You could also use spaces by calculating the differences between the lengths of the keys and values, but then you'd need to loop through them. (.join() does the same thing, it's just abstracted)

ps: you don't seem to be using the `to_write = []`, so you can probably get rid of it.